# Using Xamarin in VS2015, "No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardCornerRadius' in package '

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to use recyclerView  in my android App with Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 . And I have added those 3 Nuget packages: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4  Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView Packages
[image]

But when I build the project, I encountered these mistakes:
 RecyclerViewTutorial\Resources\layout\row.axml(2): error APT0000: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardCornerRadius' in package 'RecyclerViewTutorial.RecyclerViewTutorial'
I have updated those packages,but the problem is still here. 
What can I do now?

The .axml file code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```